# firebase/messaging does not provide an export named getToken

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have installed firebase sdk with `npm install firebase`  [like on documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "firebase.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.15.0"
  }
}
```

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //... My apiKey ... etc
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

console.log('DEBUG APP',app);
//until here everything ok I can see the app object
```

The next step on documentation is Configure Web credentials:

```
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";
//here got error:
//SyntaxError: The requested module 'firebase/messaging' does not provide an export named 'getToken'
//I tried only  import { getMessaging } ... but also not provided

const messaging = getMessaging();
// Add the public key generated from the console here.
getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: "my_wap_public_key_here"});
```

I have tried also from webpage client side (like documentation )

> Do you use ESM and want to use browser modules? Replace all your import lines to use the following pattern:
> import { } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-SERVICE.js'
> (where SERVICE is an SDK name such as firebase-firestore).

But if i try

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js';
```

I got error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: Where do you see the error? Ie is it reported as part of the build process or is it just your IDE complaining?

Comment: i run it on terminal `node firebase.js`

Comment: You cannot use the Firebase web SDK in Node.js. For that, you need to use the Admin SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: Aaaa . Ok . Thank you ... I think I've started on the wrong way :)

Comment: That sounds like an answer @Phil  --- Do you feel like posting it below, so we can get closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Web SDK is only for use in front-end / browser environments whereas Node.js is considered a **server environment**.

From the [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choosing-a-server-option)...

> #### Choosing a server option
>
> You'll need to decide on a way to interact with FCM servers: either using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#firebase-admin-sdk-for-fcm) or the raw protocols. Because of its support across popular programming languages and its convenience methods for handling authentication and authorization, the Firebase Admin SDK is the recommended method.

You can find the Node.JS Admin SDK documentation here ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#node.js